# Datagridview issue

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there any method to populate a dataGridView on a form from another class? The functions I use to connect and run queries to the DB are in a class, but I want the results to be showed in the main form. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the methods that you want to access as public.
If the class is in another project, you may have to add a reference to it in your current project.

Once the method is public, do something like this:

```
datagridview.DataSource = yourClass.GetData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As long as the other class has public methods that let you access the data you need

So, the simplest example would be something like this:

```
  // this assumes the other class method is a static method  
  datagridview1.cells[0].value = otherClass.GetStringData();
```

Also check these detailed, closely related answers out:

[How to access form objects from another cs file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717074/how-to-access-form-objects-from-another-cs-file-in-c-sharp)

[How to access form methods and controls from a class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217389/how-to-access-form-methods-and-controls-from-a-class-in-c)